# Traverse in custom GUI in j2me

Tags: java-me, custom-controls, midp, lcdui

Here is my Traverse method code

```
protected boolean traverse(int dir, int viewportWidth, int viewportHeight,
        int[] visRect_inout) {
    try {
        if (hori && vert) {
            // CustomItems items=new CustomItems("Hi");
            switch (dir) {
                case Canvas.DOWN:
                    this.a=dir;                  //Canvas.DOWN
                    this.b=viewportWidth;        //b=2
                    this.c=viewportHeight;       //c=3 
                    this.d=visRect_inout;        //d={2,2,250,250}
                    this.traverse(Canvas.UP, b, c, d);

                    break;
                case Canvas.UP:
                    this.a=dir;
                    this.j=viewportWidth;
                    this.k=viewportHeight;
                    this.d=visRect_inout;  
                    this.traverse(Canvas.UP, j, k, d);
                    break;
                case Canvas.LEFT:
                    this.a=dir;
                    this.j=viewportWidth;
                    this.k=viewportHeight;
                    this.d=visRect_inout;
                    this.traverse(Canvas.LEFT, j, k, d);
                    break;
                case Canvas.RIGHT:

                    break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am very new to Custom Item.
If I had done any wrong, let me know.

Comment: what is _CustomGUI_ ? what is _Listitem_? There are no such objects in [MIDP 2 lcdui API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html). Do you mean `CustomItem` and  `ChoiceGroup`?

Comment: @user1078616, your question is very vague and inconclusive. Support your question with more concrete context, screen shots, mention the reference libraries and development environment used.

Answer (score 0):

The way how you invoke `traverse` from within switch statement looks slippery to me:

```
                    this.traverse(Canvas.UP, b, c, d); // ...
                    // ...and similar in cases Canvas.UP, LEFT
```

The code you posted so far is quite fragmentary but as far as I can tell, above will lead to infinite recursive calls for `traverse`, eventually ending in stack overflow error.

In your particular case this might be harmless though because you unconditionally return `false` from your method. Per my understanding this means that device will never attempt to invoke traverse with `Canvas UP` and other potentially dangerous values. Feel free to check [lcdui CustomItem#traverse API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html#traverse%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d%29) for more details if you're interested.

- Given your code I think it makes good sense for you to study introductory code examples in tutorials. There are plenty available online - search the web for something like "MIDP tutorial CustomItem". Here's the link to one for example: [Adding Custom Items to MIDP 2.0 Forms](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/customitems/index.html)
   
  Also, if you are using Wireless Toolkit / Java ME SDK, you could check their code examples. Per my recollection, there were nice working examples of CustomItem code there.